# Use 3-Axis Accelerometer to calculate theta?

Tags: navigation, odometry

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

is it possible to use a 3-Axis Accelerometer to estimate theta for the odometry (on a car-like robot, without a gyroscope)?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28046/use-3-axis-accelerometer-to-calculate-theta?/) by [Cav](https://answers.ros.org/users/1633/cav/) on ROS Answers with karma: 345 on 2012-02-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You mean the yaw angle? No, you can't do that with accelerometers, as they measure linear acceleration, not angular rates like gyroscopes do (The angular rate has to be integrated to get an angle estimate in that case).

Using multiple highly accurate accelerometers placed on different parts of the vehicle one could in theory estimate the angular rate, but that's irrelevant here I guess.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2012-02-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Cav](https://answers.ros.org/users/1633/cav/) on 2012-02-20**:
Yes, that's what I meant. Thanks!